# Card for changing the type of lands in the library

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Are there any cards that convert **lands that are in the library** to any other permanent type (creature, enchantment, etc.)?

Or maybe a converter that converts all cards, that are not in play to any type, different from land type.

I want to use this to mill someone's library using [Sphinx's Tutelage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSphinx%27s%5d%2b%5bTutelage%5d).

Mycosynth Lattice is not a option as it does not affect cards that are not in play.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It's possible that there is a card that accomplish the same goal without the exact effect you mentioned.

Comment: @diego I need something to mill all cards with Sphinx Tutelage.

Answer (score 3):

There is no card with such effect.

The only card with an effect like the one you describe would be [Painter's Servant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPainter%27s%5d%2b%5bServant%5d), but it doesn't change cards type, only color.

In the case of [Sphinx's Tutelage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSphinx%27s%5d%2b%5bTutelage%5d), there is no 1-card-trick that would allow milling and entire deck with lands in it.

In legacy, a similar effect is usually achieved using the [Painter's Servant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPainter%27s%5d%2b%5bServant%5d) + [Grindstone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGrindstone%5d) combo.

Comment: The card Conspiracy does a similar thing with creature types.

Comment: @Ydrasaal That's very famous combo in Legacy. I hoped to create variation of this combo in Modern.